# What do you call a person who always thinks they are being used?

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

What do you call a person who always thinks that they're being used; a person who thinks that everyone else has an ulterior motive if someone asks them something?

For example, you might ask them if they want to go to the store with you, they'd immediately respond by saying "I'm not paying for anything!"

Or, if you ask them to hang out with you, they say "Do I look like an ATM to you? You're always trying to get me to spend money!"

This person doesn't give you a chance to finish your thoughts or intentions. They just assume that you want something from them.

Comment: I would probably call them _paranoid_, though I’m sure there are many people out there who would refer to such a person as a _wife_ or _husband_. (Incidentally, please take the time to separate your post into paragraphs and punctuate it properly. The way it is currently written, it is very cumbersome to read.)

Comment: paranoid is too harsh. that implied delusional thinking - whereas this person may have had real instances of such occurrences.

Comment: @kns98 No, _paranoid_ does not necessarily imply delusions. The narrower, clinical sense is much less common in actual language usage than the broader sense ([sense 1.1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/paranoid)): “Unreasonably or obsessively anxious, suspicious, or mistrustful”. I would certainly call a person such as this _unreasonably suspicious/mistrustful_.

Comment: As much-under-rated philosopher Mongo observes in impossible-to-over-rate *Blazing Saddles*, ["**Mongo only pawn in game of life**"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKRma7PDW10). He knows perfectly well he's just being used by other people all the time, but he doesn't let this bother him.

Comment: From the two examples, **cheap** comes to mind, as does the more general term *annoying*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is at least the third Mongo quote to make it into ELU. Who knew he was such a font of wisdom.

Comment: @PhilSweet: ***I*** knew from the first time I heard "Mongo only pawn in game of life" that we were dealing with a truly insightful guy! If he ever writes his own ["little red book"](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-34932800) I shall definitely acquire myself a copy! :)

Answer (score 3):

The second definition of ***cynical*** describes this attitude:

> **2** :  having or showing the attitude or temper of a *cynic*: as
>
> > **a** :  contemptuously distrustful of human nature and motives <those *cynical* men who say that democracy cannot be honest and efficient — F. D. Roosevelt>
> >
> > **b** :  based on or reflecting a belief that human conduct is motivated primarily by self-interest <a *cynical* ploy to win votes>
>
> <sub>(Source: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cynical))</sub>

So, you could say, "He is a *cynic*," or "He is *cynical*."

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to refer to them (politely) is *guarded*. (Cautious, reserved, suspicious - from various dictionaries.)

Answer (score 0):

What springs to my mind are "tightwad" and "jerk".

Answer (score 0):

Wary is a good word, but it's not being suspicious. I suggest leery, which means to be wary and suspicious. It checks off all the boxes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I would use 'stand offish' or confrontational. It seems like this person is protecting their territory.

Comment: _Standoffish_ and _confrontational_ are almost synonyms. While _confrontational_ can certainly be used to describe such a person, it doesn’t really describe the suspiciousness behind the constant confrontationism—there are lots of other ways to be confrontational. And _standoffish_ is not a word I can meaningfully apply to the kind of person described in the question at all.